# Can basic Geometry ever come useful to a Beginner to Intermediate skilled Java coder?

Tags: geometry

Just Curious. I'm currently foraying into the world of Java coding, and, was wondering weather Geometry can come useful in the kind of programming a Beginner to Intermediate Skill level Java coder has.

Comment: Yes, just like basic spelling and grammar skills will also come in quite useful in accomplishing real-world tasks.

Comment: To paraphrase Mark Twain: 'everyone *wonders about the weather* but no-one does anything about it'.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you will code. Java is just a language laden with tons of useful apis. But knowing a bit of geometry can never hurt. If you are gonna code a lot of layouts you might find knowledge of shapes and forms can come pretty handy.

Even without real application needs, some exercises on geometry or other forms of maths can only help you design/code better.

Answer (score 2):

It can be useful if the problems you need to solve require an application of geometry to do so.  Other than that, I think that the only benefit geometry would provide would be the added benefit of thinking critically.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by "basic". In these days of graphical user interfaces, nearly everyone needs Pythagoras sooner or later...

Answer (score 0):

You can learn Java without knowing a single point of geometry.

That being said, I can't think of many situations where knowing geometry would be a bad thing.